# How to bind commands to dynamically added buttons?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, data-binding

How can I bind a delegate command to a dynamically added `UserControl` button?

I have my `UserControl` button

```
<ItemsControl
    ItemsSource="{Binding SomeCollection}"
    HorizontalAlignment="Center">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <UniformGrid
                Columns="2" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <DMX_ControlLibrary:DMX_ItemBox
                Width="250"
                Height="150"
                FontSize="12"
                Command="{Binding ItemBoxButtonCommand}"
                Content="{Binding Path=.}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

And in my view model, I have this

```
private ICommand itemBoxButtonCommand;
public ICommand ItemBoxButtonCommand
{
    get { return (this.itemBoxButtonCommand) ?? (this.itemBoxButtonCommand = new DelegateCommand(ItemButton_Click)); }
}

private void ItemButton_Click()
{
    MessageBox.Show("");
}
```

`Binding` doesn't seem to work this way unlike it does on statically added controls.
How can I make it work?

Comment: Where is `ItemBoxButtonCommand` defined? On the items in the `SomeCollection` or in the view model that contains `SomeCollection`? How and where do you set the data context?

Comment: @thatguy It's in the viewmodel that contains SomeCollection! I have other buttons statically defined in the same context and those work fine. So i guess my commands are able to get to the code in the viewmodel. But i'm not sure if i have to do it differently for dynamically created buttons to use commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you stated in the comments for `ItemBoxButtonCommand`:

> It's in the viewmodel that contains SomeCollection!

When the data template is applied for each item in the `SomeCollection`, each `DMX_ItemBox` will get its `DataContext` set the the corresponding item, not the data context of the `ItemsControl` which contains the `SomeCollection`.

In order to bind to the `ItemBoxButtonCommand`, you can use a [`RelativeSource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.binding.relativesource?view=windowsdesktop-5.0) binding to the `DataContext` of the `ItemsControl` (which is a parent of the items).

```
<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
   <DataTemplate>
      <DMX_ControlLibrary:DMX_ItemBox
         Width="250"
         Height="150"
         FontSize="12"
         Command="{Binding DataContext.ItemBoxButtonCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"
         Content="{Binding Path=.}" />
   </DataTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
```

Alternatively, assign an `x:Name` to the `ItemControl` and refer to it with [`ElementName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.binding.elementname?view=windowsdesktop-5.0).

```
<ItemsControl
   x:Name="MyItemsControl"
   ItemsSource="{Binding SomeCollection}"
   HorizontalAlignment="Center">
   <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
      <ItemsPanelTemplate>
         <UniformGrid
            Columns="2" />
      </ItemsPanelTemplate>
   </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
   <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <DMX_ControlLibrary:DMX_ItemBox
            Width="250"
            Height="150"
            FontSize="12"
            Command="{Binding DataContext.ItemBoxButtonCommand, ElementName=MyItemsControl}"
            Content="{Binding Path=.}" />
      </DataTemplate>
   </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```